# GLKit's -drawRect: is not called during screen rotation

Tags: ios, glkit, screen-rotation, autorotate, glkview

I have `GLKit`-based app with some simple object displayed.

All works fine, except screen rotation, during which `GLKView` is not updated (`-drawRect:` is not called). So during rotation projection matrix is not updated according to dynamically changing screen sizes and object looks badly (stretched).

Comment: Are you using shaders or GLKBaseEffect?

Comment: Tried both: `GLKBaseEffect` and my own shaders - the same result. `-drawRect:` will be called after animation finished - so any GL rendering (that we normally place there) will be suspended to that moment.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking that maybe the projectionMatrix property on GLKBaseEffect was buggy. I'll have a think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply not how UIKit animations work. I sort-of explain how half of it works in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693539/layoutsubviews-during-an-animation/3693650#3693650), but I'll try to summarize the relevant bits:

- Everything is a textured rectangle. (There are some exceptions, like perhaps CAShapeLayer, but this is true for the most part.)
- `UIView`'s properties are linked to CALayer's "model tree" properties. They change *instantaneously*.
- Animations work by animating the "presentation tree" properties from the starting value to the current model value.
- The starting value of the animation is, by default, the previous model value. Specifying `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` makes it use the current presentation value.

There are, of course, a few exceptions (`CAShapeLayer` seems to be more than a textured rect, `UIScrollView` does scrolling animations on a timer, UIView transitions are another thing entirely...).

How rotation is *supposed* to work is that you get a single `-setFrame:`, everything is laid out (and potentially rerendered), and then the animatable properties are animated. By default, this means things will rerender to the new dimensions but get stretched to fit the old dimensions, and then animate (and unstretch) as the rotation progresses.

That said, `GLKView` might work differently. If you're using `GLKViewController`, it might even suspend rendering during the rotation animation. You could try calling `-setNeedsDisplay` during the rotation, but it won't help much since the frame is already set to its final value.

Probably the easiest way to handle the rotation animation yourself is to force a non-animated relayout to the rotated frame and then do some fudging in the renderer (the black border and status bar animate separately though).

Alternatively, the traditional way is to make your VC portrait-only and handle the device orientation notifications yourself, but this is a big can of worms (you then have to worry about the status bar orientation which determines things like the touch offset and keyboard orientation, and it tends to interacts "interestingly" when transitioning to/from other VCs).

Answer (score 6):

This might be a shot in the dark since I don't have any experience with `GLKit`, however I do have experience with `UIView` and `-drawRect:`.  Try changing the contentMode of the view in question to redraw:

`view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;`

This will tell the view that it needs to redraw it's contents when it's boundaries change.  Otherwise, `UIView` will simply attempt to scale it's contents (the default for contentMode is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`).  The reason for this is that it's a lot easier to scale what's there than to redraw the contents and `UIView` is designed to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make any difference in practice on a GLKView.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that at some point early in your application lifecycle, enable device orientation changes.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Then when your view is instantiated register for a notification like so.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

Then implement `-deviceOrientationDidChange:` in your view controller and call `-setNeedsDisplay`

Comment: `-...DidChange` will be called after orientation change happened. And this time `drawRect:` will be called also (cause I update matrices by time & on each frame change). But I need to apply changes during this process.

Comment: I see now.  I though you were saying that you were not getting any rotation information at all.  Listen for and implement the view controller method `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`.  The duration will allow you to calculate your animations during the transition.

Comment: Yes, I know. And I can also reimplement view's `-setFrame:` - and will get view size changes each animation step. But I can't respond to this changes - I mean, I can update projection matrix, but updates won't be applied, because `-drawRect:` (and corresponding GL drawing) wan't be called until animation finished.